# How do i write console app in java like in C lang ?

Tags: java, macos, terminal, console-application, command-prompt

Basically, i want to run a console application in java (just like in C language) in both mac and windows. So to start i am using these functions 
to start command prompt, i don't know how to proceed further to **display some text and get inputs from the same terminal/ command prompt after starting it programmatically**. I am not able to obtain /path/to/the/executable programmatically for mac as well.

```
public static void startTerminalOfMac(){
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/open -a Terminal /path/to/the/executable");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void startCommandPromptOfWindows(){
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe");
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Can you guide in this matter ? The above functions are just a start. **My basic question is how to write console application in java on mac and windows (similar to console app in C language) ?**

Comment: Why would you start a console from your program instead of starting your program from a console???

Comment: As a short guidance: use `System.in` and `System.out` for text input/output and [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for communicating with the shell process.

Comment: I want to deliver an executable jar file. So when that is double clicked, naturally command prompt has to open. How else will i display console and take inputs from user?

Comment: @samo by using "java -jar YourProgram.jar" in command prompt.

Comment: @JackWhitelll I thought customer would not be knowing that stuff. He wants to double click and then answer questions i ask through command prompt.

Comment: @MarkoŽivanović How to use process builder to open terminal in mac?

Comment: @samo I'm not overly familiar with Mac, but, I guess starting /bin/sh should do the trick, same as Unix/Linux.

Comment: @MarkoŽivanović Will System.in and System.out work on the opened prompt/ terminal through process builder? What do i do to use in and out with the same prompt/terminal that is opened using process builder?

Comment: @samo System in and out provide streams to your console. ProcessBuilder provides streams to processes input and output. It's your job to shuttle data between them.

Comment: Finally i am telling customer to enter "java -jar Myprogram.jar" which works on both mac and windows, there is no need to drag this to complexity. Thanks @JackWhitelll.

Comment: @samo you might ship a .bat/.sh-file that starts your application, so the user will still be able to start it using a double click.